# How can i add the column name in every sheet of excel file in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have 6 sheets in my excel file and i need to copy the date from file name and append the same in every sheet as new column as date.but with this code i can change only in first sheet.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path = 'XXXX'

for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfile = [ _ for _ in files if _.endswith('.xlsx')]

for xlsf in xlsfile: 
    print(xlsf)
    df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(roots, xlsf))
    df['filename'] = xlsf.split("-") [-2]
    df.to_excel(os.path.join(roots, xlsf), index = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'XXXX'

for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    xlsfile = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.xlsx')]

    for xlsf in xlsfile:
        print(xlsf)
        excel_path = os.path.join(roots, xlsf)
        xls = pd.ExcelFile(excel_path)

        with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
            for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
                df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
                df['filename'] = xlsf.split("-")[-2]
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).